# How to pass id to jQuery onshow, onload

Tags: jquery, timer, triggers, onload, countdown

I'm using JavaScript function to set Timer Countdown based on id.I need to dynamically pass id to jQuery when div is opened (I have multi timers on different divs and different IDs (timespan, timespan1, timespan2...) and I modified JS to jQuery in ordeer to do it. When I specifically name the id, Timer work ok but I cannot manage to automatically pass the id to jQuery.
This is JS function I use and it works with id=timespan:

```
<script>
        var CCOUNT = 10;
        var t, count;

        function cddisplay() {
            // displays time in span
            document.getElementById('timespan').innerHTML = count;
        };

        function countdown() {
            // starts countdown
            cddisplay();
            if (count == 0) {
                // time is up
            } else {
                count--;
                t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
            }
        };

        function cdpause() {
            // pauses countdown
            clearTimeout(t);
        };

        function cdreset() {
            // resets countdown
            cdpause();
            count = CCOUNT;
            cddisplay();
        };
    </script>
```

This is how I modified it to jQuery in order to pass specific id to function and it does not work

```
<script>
        var CCOUNT = 10;
        var t, count;

        function cddisplay(id) {
            // displays time in span
            $(document.getElementById('#' + id)).innerHTML = count;
        };

        function countdown() {
            // starts countdown
            cddisplay();
            if (count == 0) {
                // time is up
            } else {
                count--;
                t = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
            }
        };

        function cdpause() {
            // pauses countdown
            clearTimeout(t);
        };

        function cdreset() {
            // resets countdown
            cdpause();
            count = CCOUNT;
            cddisplay();
        };
    </script>
```

And this is HTML

```
<div class="flex relative auto-id" onclick="TradeThis4(this.id); cdreset(this.id)" style="width: 100%; display: none;">
  <div class="relative flex-1">
     <div class="px-3 text-xs text-center text-white border border-red-700">
        <div class="text-xxs">
                                                I SELL <span class="curr-">EUR</span> <span class="qty1">10000</span> • I BUY <span class="curr-RSD">RSD</span> <span class="qty2">1000000</span>
        </div>
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:31px; margin:0 ;">
          <div style="float:left; display: inline-block; margin:0 auto; width:50%; cursor: pointer;">
                                                    1.10<span class="text-3xl font-bold leading-none">28</span>3
          </div>
        <div class="text-2xl timer" onload="cddisplay(this.id)" id="timespan" style="float:right; width:50%; pointer-events:none">
                                                    10
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="text-xxs">
                                                CLICK ON PRICE TO CONFIRM SELL
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have suggestion why I cannot pass id timespan to jQuery and start Timer onload or onshow...?

Answer (score 0):

1. Note that Your parent div has style `display:none;`
2. `$(document.getElementById('#' + id)).innerHTML = count;`  is not correct Syntex in jQuery

The correct Syntex to change html from ID selector in jQuery is:

```
$("#"+id).html(count);
```

You should not write function name in string. Write function name like:

```
t = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

Comment: I've corrected them but still does not pass id to function

Comment: @Gibb I think You should not assign `onload` event on div element

Comment: What should I do instead?

Comment: Call the function when document is loaded: `cddisplay("timespan")`

Comment: id=cddisplay("timespan")?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: @Gibb Can you please explain more clearly step wise what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to automatically pass the ID to function. I have a lot of DIVs with timers on page, every div has its own ID. I cannot make one function for every ID (40+), but instead to pass ID to function when DIV become visible (note above that div is display: none). In that case, when client open DIV with id="timesan" timer should start for that DIV, when user open DIV with id="timespan5", timer should start for that DIV etc.

Comment: load event does not fire when your css change to `display: block` or anything. Load event is not suitable for this problem.

Comment: I agree, just can not figure it out know which event works

Comment: Not events, it is better to attach in function where you change display of div.